# Why cant I import dates from a csv file in mysql?

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into a table in mysql (mariadb). the import is working for the most part, but I cant get the date fields to update. The csv file has 6 columns (among others) with time/date stamps. All the columns in the csv are represented in the table so it should be a straight forward import:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY 
    LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\nyxcrap\\EspoCRM\\SalesForce Import\\05-30-20\\IMPORT\\Task split\\test-import.csv' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `espocrm`.`temp_task` 
    CHARACTER SET utf8 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES (
        `id`, 
        `name`, 
        `deleted`, 
        `status`, 
        `priority`, 
        `date_start`, 
        `date_end`, 
        `date_start_date`, 
        `date_end_date`, 
        `date_completed`, 
        `description`, 
        `created_at`, 
        `modified_at`, 
        `parent_id`, 
        `parent_type`, 
        `account_id`, 
        `contact_id`, 
        `created_by_id`, 
        `modified_by_id`, 
        `assigned_user_id`, 
        `type_of`
    );'
```

(NOTE: no I'm not concerned about security here. this is in a pretty deeply walled garden I'm in, and I think seeing the full command as I typed it may help)

The import works fine except for the dates, this is the output:

```
`/* 0 rows imported in 0.219 seconds. */
SHOW WARNINGS;
/* Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date_start' at row 1 */
/* Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date_end' at row 1 */
/* Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date_end_date' at row 1 */
/* Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date_completed' at row 1 */
/* Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 1 */
/* Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'modified_at' at row 1 */`
```

I'm not sure why it says "0 rows imported", it imported some 20000 rows just fine! however, the dates are all 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
As for the table, these specific columns are all set for either DATE or DATETIME... so... what am I missing here?

Additional notes: I'm connecting to the server using HeidiSQL over an ssh (plink/putty) connection. the server is running ubuntu 19.04 LTS in a simple LAMP build with the default configs for just about everything. This is for an espoCRM server. yes Espo has it's own data import utilities, but there aren't any sanity checks and the data we have is just large enough it crashes the import tools. besides, I'd rather just import the data raw.

Comment: please provide a sanitized sample of the csv and also a SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_task

Comment: The likelihoood is that the date data from the csv file is somehow not in the appropriate format for the corresponding column. Perhaps you are trying to import a date/time into a date or vice-versa, or dates are not in mysql format. It is not possible to pinpoint the issue without the information @nbk requested

Comment: Found the issue. though I'm not sure why. I cleaned up the csv files using excel. Opening the files in notepad++ revealed they were US formatted and not UK formatted ("mm/dd/yy" instead of "yyyy-mm-dddd hh:mm:ss")... again I'm not sure why excel showed one thing and saved another, that's not normal behavior as far as I know. either way, I managed to get the data/time stamps corrected with a bit of copy/paste shenanigans.